# Network login sign in screen

Tags: networking, login

I am touring Spain staying at a number of campsites which offer Wi-fi but ask for a username and password. On my Android tablet I connect to the Wi-fi and get a 'sign onto network ' message which opens a web page to enter the username and password.

I can connect to the network with my Raspberry pi but can see no way to sign into the network.

I have tried to add the network and password in the wpa-supplicant file but that seems to stop wireless access totally.

Comment: What do you want to do with the RasPi? You do not want to use an internet browser with it?